# How can I generate an NSDate object that represents the current time in UTC?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsdate

I'm new to iOS and I'm trying to understand how to use dates and formatters to create a date object that represents the current time, but in the UTC time zone. That is, if my local time on my device is 3pm PST, I want to create a date object that represents the time 3pm UTC. I do NOT want to convert 3pm PST to the UTC equivalent, but instead create the 3pm UTC date using the 3pm PST local time date. My current code is...

```
NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:utcTimeZone];
NSString *nowInUTCString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

...but this essentially converts my local time to UTC time, which is what I do NOT want. I'm still reading up on the docs, but I thought I'd post this in the meantime. Any help?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: To create an NSDate object that represents the current time in UTC you say `[NSDate date]`.

Comment: (Keep in mind that internally an NSDate is ALWAYS UTC (unless you muck it up).  Time zones only get involved in converting to/from "display" times via NSDateFormatter et al.)

Comment: (Also remember that NSDate objects do not contain any format information.  They contain JUST the date/time, relative to GMT/UTC.)

Comment: UTC and GMT are the same time zone. Look in the documentation.

Comment: BTW, the above code is asking for the date to be returned relative to the UTC timezone.  If you wanted PST you should ask for it (or let timezone default).

Comment: @HotLicks Please read my question again, I don't want the current time in UTC. I want the UTC version of the current time. In other words, if it's 3pm PST, then it's 11pm UTC. I don't want 11pm UTC, I want 3pm UTC. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JuanCatalan, sorry that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Not a lot.  If you want the current local time, only with "UTC" tacked on, why not just format without timezone and tack on "UTC"?

Comment: (You didn't fix the other typo.)

Comment: @HotLicks, fixed and thank you, I'll do that, it just felt a little hacky.

Comment: (What is the reason for wanting a date manipulated the way you describe?)

Comment: @HotLicks, it's none of your concern, but thank you for your help.

Comment: If you explained why you need this we could offer alternate solutions.  For instance, if this is for some sort of calendaring app then you need to do your conversions in the timezone of the user of the calendar.

Comment: @HotLicks, my question is very straightforward, MJN answered it well. Thank you again.

Comment: For some reason the better answer was deleted -- just add/subtract the timezone offset to the NSDate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should let the system do all the date math for you. Doing date math yourself may lead to bugs.

We can use `NSCalendar` to convert dates to date components and back. `NSDateComponents` has a timezone property that we can set. We'll get back the date that represents it's timezone and components.

```
// grab the current calendar and date
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

// create UTC date components
NSDateComponents *utcComponents = [cal components: NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate: now];
utcComponents.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName: @"UTC"];

// get the UTC date
NSDate *utcDate = [cal dateFromComponents: utcComponents];
```

I'm in Pacific time and got the following printout.

```
NSLog(@"%@", utcDate); // 2013-08-29 12:09:52 +0000 (my time converted to UTC)
NSLog(@"%@", now);     // 2013-08-29 19:09:52 +0000 (right now in UTC)
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but this looks like it converts my local time to UTC time, which is not what I'm trying to do. Am I reading this right?

Comment: This takes everything about your current time, and changes only the timezone. Just what you're asking for. :)

Comment: Yeah, I was misreading it, I see now. Thanks, MJN, this looks great!

Comment: You're welcome! Also, don't forget to checkout the WWDC time/date videos. They're super interesting and introduce lots of best practices.